# Using linq to return an object with a list<object> member

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am still somewhat new to Linq to SQL.  I am looking for a way to get all members of an object by using a single linq query.  The problem I haev run into is that one of the class members is a list of custom objects.  It goes something like this:

Class:

```
public class RoomConfiguration
{
    public int ConfigID {get;set;}
    public string ConfigName { get; set; }
    public int RowCount { get; set; }
    public int ColCount { get; set; }
    public int FillDirection { get; set; }
    public string BigDoor { get; set; }
    public string SmallDoor { get; set; }
    public List<LineConfig> Lines { get; set; }
}
```

I am looking for a linq query that will fill in all of the members of this class, including  Lines.  The data for Lines comes from another table which I have defined a class for as well.

Thank you to anyone who may have a solution for this.  Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little hard, not knowing how your tables relate, but you could do this:

```
var configs = db.RoomConfigurations
                .Select( r => new RoomConfiguration
                 {
                     ConfigID = r.ConfigID,
                     ConfigName = r.ConfigName,
                     ...
                     Lines = db.LineConfigs
                               .Where( l => l.RoomConfigID == r.ConfigID )
                               .ToList()
                 });
```

Or

```
var configs = db.RoomConfigurations
                .Join( db.LineConfigs, r => r.ConfigID, l => l.RoomConfigID, (r,l) => new { RoomConfig = r, LineConfigs = l } )
                .GroupBy( j => j.RoomConfig )
                .Select( g => new RoomConfiguration
                 {
                     ConfigID = g.Key.ConfigID,
                     ConfigName = g.Key.ConfigName,
                     ...
                     Lines = g.LineConfigs.ToList()
                 });
```