# Creating object with nested object list using LINQ to Entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am trying to create an object that contains the list of objects using Linq to Entity Framework. But I am getting NotSupported exception. My db structure is very similar to the db that comes with LinqPad. Let’s take that for example – I have a `customer` domain object and `Purchase` (or for ex  - Order) domain object.

```
Public Class Customer (){ long CustID ,string CustName , List<Purchase> purchases }
Public Class Purchase () { long PurchaseID}
```

I am trying to populate the Customer domain object in DAL using the navigation properties like this -

```
db.Customer
.Where( t=> t.CustID==1)  //hard coding for 1
.Select( t=> new Customer()
{
CustName = t.name ,
Purchases = t.Customer.Purchase
        .Select ( p=> new Purchase()
            {
                PurchaseID=p.purchaseid
}).ToList()
});
```

I got the `NotSpported` exception for this

I also tried creating a method for `purchases – GetPurchases()`. It returns the list of purchases  and assigned it to the customer object that I am creating up. But I am still getting the same exception.
I am getting `NotSuuported` exception with error message –

> cannot convert method to store expression

. I searched  and it seems like its supported in linq to sql but not in linq to ef. I am trying to do the same thing like this post - [Using linq to return an object with a list<object> member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558144/using-linq-to-return-an-object-with-a-listobject-member)
Is it possible to populate the domain object like I am doing. Are there any known solutions or work around for this.

Comment: What line is giving you the exception?

Comment: I was getting error on this - Purchases = t.Customer.Purchase
        .Select ( p=> new Purchase()
            {
                PurchaseID=p.purchaseid
}).ToList()

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example of something similar. In this case it is the nested Taxes collection that is being populated.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ServiceLayer.DTO.Vendor>> GetAllVendors()
{
    return await (

        from vendor in _db.Vendors

        select new ServiceLayer.DTO.Vendor()
        {
            Id = vendor.Id,
            Name = vendor.Name,
            Taxes = (from tax in _db.VendorTaxes
                     where tax.VendorId.Equals(vendor.Id)
                     select new DTO.VendorTax() { Id = tax.Id, Rate = tax.Rate })
        })

    .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: This works but I'm finding it to be tremendously slow in generating the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It can't convert:

```
.Select ( p=> new Purchase()
            {
                PurchaseID=p.purchaseid
})
```

to proper sql statement, in fact it will makes expression tree, but can't convert it to sql command, you can do something like this:

```
db.Customer
.Where( t=> t.CustID==1)  //hard coding for 1
.Select( t=> new Customer()
{
CustName = t.name ,
Purchases = t.Customer.Purchase
        .Select ( p=> p.purchaseid)
        .ToList() // here you should fetch your data from DB

        // now convert fetched data via linq2object to what you want:
        .Select( p => new Purchase()
            {
                PurchaseID=p.purchaseid
            })
        .ToList();
```

**Edit:** Sorry I didn't see your first select statement:

```
Select( t=> new Customer()
{
 CustName = t.name ,
 Purchases = t.Customer.Purchase...
}
```

linq2entity Also can't handle this (in fact any complex initialization)

But as I can see, Seems you just have one customer, so why you didn't get it totally? in fact doing so:

```
var customer = db.Customer.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID == 1)
```

?

Comment: @user1165359, After you test it, and you see this works for you, you can mark it as answer by toggling tic mark in left hand side of my answer to green.

Comment: Hi Saeed , I am getting the same error - can not convert to store expression , NotSupportedException.

Comment: Is your purchaceid complex property?

Comment: No its not a complex property.I found this article - http://mosesofegypt.net/post/LINQ-to-Entities-what-is-not-supported.aspx on internet about this . I was just wondering if there are some other solutions for this issue . Thanks for responding to my post and you suggestion.I appreciate it.

Comment: @user1165359, I didn't see your first `Select` statement, If you have just one customer you can do what I suggest but in too many customer it's better to write your own sp.

Comment: Saeed , this - var customer = db.Customer.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID == 1) will give the EF Customer and not my domain entity customer , thats why in first select I am projecting the ef customer to domain customer.My ef customer has 10 properties my my domain customer doesnt have all the properties.

Comment: @user1165359, In this case I suggest add CustomerID to your domain and DB Objects now you can do: `db.Customer.Purchases.Where(x=>x.CustomerID == 1).Select(x=>x.PurchaseID)`, After creating purchase list you can similary make your customer, Also sp (stored procedure) is another option.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate an entity of your model in a `Select` statement. `Select` is for creating objects with "selected" properties/columns - anonymous objects or (for example) View Models or Data Transfer Objects.

What you are trying to load (an entity including navigation properties) is usually done with eager loading:

```
var customer = db.Customer.Include("Purchases")
    .SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustID == 1);
```

You generally also cannot use your custom methods (like `GetPurchases()`) in a LINQ to Entities query. There are only few exceptions - like extension methods of `IQueryable<T>` or methods which return an `Expression<Func<T>>`. In most cases Entity Framework cannot convert such a custom method into a "Store Expression" in a language your database can understand (= SQL for example).

Comment: Slauma , There are two reasons for which I am not using Include.1) Lets say I have Customer connected to Order which is connect to Status.I can not use this - db.Customer.Include("Order").Include("Status") as this requires both the two tables - Order and Status should be connected to Customer table .Correct me if I am wrong but I think Include will not work If I have relation like this - tables 1-->2-->3  , it works for relation like 1--> 2 and 1--> 3  .2) With Include I think I am sending the complete object set to client and when the client will use it then only the query will be executed..

Comment: I want the query to be executed from DAL and not from the client.

Comment: @user1165359: For point 1 you can use `Include("Order.Status")` to fetch deeper levels in the hierarchy. This works with eager loading. For point 2: `Include` (=eager loading) will load the related objects together with the base object in one DB roundtrip. The query is executed by `ToList` or `SingleOrDefault`. You can do this in the DAL and the whole object graph gets materialized.

Comment: I think in that case I can use Include .Thanks for clearing up the Include.