# List of lists in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, windows-phone

I have an issue with storing List of lists in database, entity for my problem might look as follows:

```
[Table]
class Entity
{
    [Column]
    public List<string> names;
    public List<EntitySet<Entity>> linkSets;
}
```

Each name of Entity::names corresponds to one object from the Entity::linkSets which, in turn contains references to other Entity objects. First of all, I doubt that my project of database, which contains only 1 table is good. I could create second table that would store linkSets and an id for each of them, and everything would become simple, because Entity would just store list of id's from linkSets table. Nevertheless, I would really like to store everything in one table, so is ther a possibility to store List of EntitySets in one column, and if so, how or what annotations should I use?
Thanks for all the replies!

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to build a heirarchical structure of `Entity`, is that right? Does an `Entity` have any additional information, other than what you've listed here?

Comment: Yes, Entity has plenty of additional fields with data, and every Entity should have list of lists of similar Entities (Entities with similar content). But my question is, if there is a possibility with EntityFramework (I'm writing for WP7/8 ) to store nested lists.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not entirely sure that you'd be able to set up that mapping directly with EF, you might be able to achieve the effect you're after though, see if this is of any use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977149/creating-object-with-nested-object-list-using-linq-to-entities

Comment: As far as my experience is involved, it is not possible directly, although I did it once, but You'll need a few additional tables in database for every nested list.